# IE9 Quirks mode - Doctype statement commented out

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, doctype, quirks-mode

I'm having an issue where IE9 is rendering a single page on my site in Quirks mode.

http://www.bettereverafter.com/index.php?fc=module&module=blockwishlistpro&controller=view&token=E5D343F0E9D5C666

For some reason, it is taking the DOCTYPE delcaration in my header file and commenting out.  The Doctype I am using is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

It seems to be pulling in some additional code, which I think is coming from here:

It looks like it is getting called here:

```
private function _displayProducts($id_wishlist)
{
    global $cookie;
    include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/WishListpro.php');
    include_once(_PS_CLASS_DIR_.'/Message.php');
echo "  
<script type='text/javascript'> 
// <![CDATA[
ThickboxI18nImage = 'Image';
ThickboxI18nOf = '/';
ThickboxI18nClose = 'X';
ThickboxI18nOrEscKey = 'Esc';
ThickboxI18nNext = '>';
ThickboxI18nPrev = '<';
tb_pathToImage = '"._MODULE_DIR_.self::modulename."/img/loadingAnimation.gif';
//]]> 
</script>";
```

My issue is, that code is not actually in the header file, it's coming from somewhere else.  I have no idea how it is getting loaded before the actual header file though...

I have already tried adding  but that doesn't do anything.

Every other page seems to work fine, just this one.  If I force it into IE9 Standards, it looks fine.  Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by having this code before your doctype:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
// <![CDATA[
    ThickboxI18nImage = 'Image';
    ThickboxI18nOf = '/';
    ThickboxI18nClose = 'X';
    ThickboxI18nOrEscKey = 'Esc';
    ThickboxI18nNext = '>';
    ThickboxI18nPrev = '<';
    tb_pathToImage = '/modules/blockwishlistpro/img/loadingAnimation.gif';
//]]>
</script>
```

You cannot have anything (not even a comment) before your doctype or IE will render in quirks mode instead of standards mode.

Comment: Besides, any tags before the doctype make the page invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I look into that, but I'm not sure how to solve that problem though, see my updated question.  Thanks!

Comment: Without being able to see all the different php files it is hard to identify what is causing the issue. As a work around though, if you put this tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` in the `<head>` of your document it will force IE to render in the latest standards mode i.e. you wouldn't have to do it manually in each browser.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I tried it though and it doesn't seem to make a difference...
Re. the PHP files, is there something I should look out for?  I'm pretty sure I have the right snippet, as it seems to be the only place with that bit of script

Comment: Sorry, I am too used to writing html5. You will need to add in the closing `/` like this `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`. Hopefully that will make it work. If that doesn't work, I don't know what else to suggest. Also it doesn't look like you copied the whole of the function into your question.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either...
Re. the PHP files, the function is really long so I only included the part that looked relevant